# Laravel eloquent in a loop

Tags: php, mysql, loops, laravel, eloquent

I have an Eloquent query in a foreach loop. 
My `League` model is correct, when I echo values, I get correct `$match->league_id` inside the loop.
I have relative records in my database with that `$match->league_id`.

```
foreach ($matchesRaw as $k=>$match) {
    $lg= League::find($match->league_id)->first();
    echo  $lg->name;
}
```

My problem is my code displays only the first row (`$lg->name`) in the database. It means my query all the times gets the first row. No matter what is `$match->league_id` comes in the loop. How can I solve this?

Comment: If you properly set the relationships, you can have something like `$match->league->name->first()`.

Comment: @user2094178 You'd rather not call `first` on the model's proerty..

Comment: @JarekTkaczyk Even if he eager loads it?

Comment: @user2094178 You don't call **any** method on the model's property (table field, like `name`), because obviously it will cause error. It's totally different from calling it on the relation object, relation result (collection) as **dynamic property** and so on.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you should use join in instead of  calling another eloquent object in a loop ..You understand

Comment: You should still provide some code example, as this really only partially answers the question.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that you're calling `first` like this:

```
League::first();
```

So yes, it gets always the first row in that table.

This is because you do just the same as:

```
$leagueModel = League::find($someId); // returns model
$leagueModel->first() == League::first(); // returns the same model
```

Instead you simply call `League::find($someId)`, no `first` at all.

Comment: Hi Mr. Tkaczyk, can't he do `$match->league->first()->name`? I have this similar behavior in some of my views.

Comment: He can, but it will again call `League::first()` since `$match->league` returns single model. You're refering to something like `$league->teams->first()` where first() is called on the collection, not single model.